# GridView in baseadapter auto height

Tags: android, gridview

I have this layout for an baseadapter. The TextView is filled from this adapter and gridview for a second baseadapter from the first adapter. The height of the gridview should depend on the content that is inside ( may vary ). But in may case the gridview on any row for the first baseadapter is like the height of a one row. It does not expand to fill up all the content

The layout_height = wrap_content should do the trick, right?

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:orientation="vertical" >
<TextView
    android:id="@+id/nume_carte"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:textColor="#ffffff"
    android:layout_gravity="center"
    android:textSize="15dp" >
</TextView>
<GridView 
    android:id="@+id/listare_capitole"
    android:numColumns="auto_fit"
    android:gravity="center"
    android:columnWidth="45dp"
    android:stretchMode="columnWidth"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_below="@+id/nume_carte"
    >
</GridView>
</LinearLayout>
```

The layout that fill the gridview for my second baseadater :

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:layout_width="wrap_content"
android:layout_height="wrap_content"
android:padding="5dp" >

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/id_capitol"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:textColor="#ffffff"
    android:background="@drawable/border"
    android:padding="8dp" 
    android:layout_gravity="center"
    android:textSize="15dp" >
</TextView>
```

Comment: my second baseadater :
try with match_parent in width within linearlayout & textview .

Comment: nope. it does not work...:(